# Specific URL Rewriting with parameters in wordpress

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess

I'm rewriting a website that was originally in Drupal and has very specific URL's. 
So, I need to rewrite all the original URL's to the wordpress system + the parameters for my own-written plugins:

I need to get from this:

```
http://www.domain.com/param1/param2/param3/param4/param5/detail
```

To this:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php/detail/?param=param5
```

If the last part of the url = "detail*SOMETHING*"

I've tried this (and many variations on it):

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([detail_]+.*)/?  \
  /wp1/index.php/detail/?gref=$5    [PT]
```

placed in front of the Wordpress code in .htaccess, but all I get is my Wordpress 404 page.

Any help is appreciated!!!!!

EDIT:

Full .htaccess added:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp1/
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([detail_]+.*)/?  \
/index.php/detail/?gref=$5    [PT]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp1/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Do your target URLs 200 or 404?

Is your WP in a directory? Your example URL is `http://www.domain.com/index.php/detail/?param=param5` but you are rewriting to `/wp1/index.php/detail/?gref=$5`

Comment: I target for 200, not 404. The original url is from the previous (drupal) system, and indeed, curently my WP is in a directory (wp1), as it is still in development. On the production server it will not be in a directory.

Comment: So if you try to go to a target URL of the form `http://www.domain.com/wp1/index.php/detail/?param=param5` do you get a 200 or a 404?  What parameter values might `gref` have on a working URL?  How do you want your `detailSOMETHING` to be broken up for use in your target URL?

Comment: `http://www.domain.com/param1/param2/param3/param4/param5/detail` has 5 directories in it but `^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([detail_]+.*)/?` has 6.  Is that part of the problem?

Comment: Hi Andy, Indeed, there was a 5 vs 6 param issue. I changed it, but it still gives me the 404. If I go to the index.php/detail/ url, I get a 200 page. Gref is a unique ID, and can be any 6-char string. DetailSOMETHING can be anything starting with "detail_".

Comment: What's in your full .htaccess file?

Comment: Added in the original description

Comment: And it's WP that is issuing the 404 and not Apache?

Comment: In this configuration: yes, it's WP that's issuing the 404. I get the header of the WP-page that I'm referring to. When I'm trying out some other .htaccess stuff, I sometimes do get an Apache 404.

Comment: @Borniet Were you able to resolve this question?

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan yes indeed, I was, using the WP Url parsing possibilities (see the chosen answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the info in the comments, here's my preliminary answer, hopefully helping to debug the issue rather than a fix as I can't see enough info for that — not the OP's fault, rewrite debugging is just a pain.

The rewrite rule is obviously passing something to WP but WP isn't happy with it.

What I'd do is add some debugging code to your theme's 404.php that can show you the URL called and also the URL that WP is failing to parse.  That at least will let you see whether your rewrite rule is doing what you expect.

Two other points though:

1 - If you don't move your own htaccess code outside WP's BEGIN and END then your changes will be overwritten if ever your site performs a hard save of its rewrites.

2 - It might be seen as better practice to code rewrite rules for your old URL structure within WP as a plugin instead of rewriting in htaccess.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and help! As for point 2: How would that be done? Do you happen to have any resource of info on that? Can I just "grab" everything that comes in from the first URL? If that is so, I would indeed be able to convert it to anything I want.

Comment: Well, that's the way that WP handles all a site's URLs, so it just seems natural and perhaps neater to hook in there too.  There are pretty good articles about the web if you Google "how to add rewrite rules to wordpress" or "wordpress rewrite api". http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-rewrite-api-the-basics--wp-25474 is a good introduction. There are also great answers on this site, just search for "rewrite" and sort by vote.

Comment: And to answer your last question, yes you effectively see the whole of the URL and WP gives you tools to parse it and end up with a query that WP can handle.

Comment: Damn, thanks for those tips! That's where I still fall short :-) Just my first heavy steps in WP development ;-)

Comment: FWIW you can't do better than get yourself a good book on plugin development.  Once you make the effort to learn the WP way of doing things, you find out that WP's APIs do so much of the hard work for you.